# Jboss7 ejb bean reference to container-configuration

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

In my legacy application (jboss 4.2) I have the jboss.xml code like that

```
... 
<entity>
  <ejb-name>ClaimCentreRoleBean</ejb-name>
  <local-jndi-name>ejb/entity/ClaimCentreRoleLocalHome</local-jndi-name>
  <configuration-name>Standard CMP 2.x EntityBean NoLock</configuration-name>
   <method-attributes>
       <method>
           <method-name>get*</method-name>
           <read-only>true</read-only>
       </method>
   </method-attributes>
</entity>
...
```

which references container configuration `Standard CMP 2.x EntityBean NoLock` defined in `standardjboss.xml` as follows

```
...
<container-configuration extends="Standard CMP 2.x EntityBean">
    <container-name>Standard CMP 2.x EntityBean NoLock</container-name>
    <locking-policy>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.lock.NoLock</locking-policy>
    <commit-option>D</commit-option>
</container-configuration>
...
```

I googled around and looked through stack-overflow topics, however failed to find any directions how to translate it to jboss7 way? I assume jboss.xml is not supported any more so I need to convert it into jboss-ejb3.xml, which does not support `configuration-name` attribute.

Have someone experienced the same problem? Any solutions or directions to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only solution to drop this and comment out.

If some particular interceptors mechanisms are required - then could be added on bean basis (e.g. using `<assembly-descriptor>`).
Locking - e.g. `default-entity-bean-optimistic-locking` as per https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/JBossAS7+-+Standalone+Server+-+EJB3+Service